# Sending array between class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++14

i have a a problem. I wanna create new array of `IOBjekt`, I have filled array and now I would like to send array to another class (`Hra`). Can you help me with pointers. I dont know how to foreach this array and call method from object.

Save to array

```
IObjekt **store = new IObjekt*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    store[i] = new BMPObjekt(aHraciaPlocha, "ball.bmp");

    cout << store[i] << endl;
}

aHra = new Engine(aHraciaPlocha, *store);
```

Parse array

```
Engine::Engine(ISystem * plocha, IObjekt *objekty)
    :aHraciaPlocha(plocha), aObjekty(objekty), aSkore(0)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        IObjekt *objekt = &objekty[i]; // This doesnt work
        cout << objekt->dajX << endl; 

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The 3 in your outer code is at a different level of indirection than the 3 in `Engine::Engine`.  Either remove a level of indirection in the outer code or add one in `Engine::Engine`.

Comment: Do you really need all those pointers and c-style arrays? Can't you do with a standard container like `vector` and passing a `reference` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the relationship between `BMPObjekt` and `IObjekt` (which you did not show) prevents you from easily removing a level of indirection from the outer code.  So you need to add a level of indirection to the called code, removing a `*` from the call:

```
aHra = new Engine(aHraciaPlocha, store);
```

...

```
Engine::Engine(ISystem * plocha, IObjekt **objekty)
    :aHraciaPlocha(plocha), aObjekty(objekty), aSkore(0)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        IObjekt *objekt = objekty[i];
        cout << objekt->dajX << endl; 

    }

}
```

Comment: It show me error `ErrorC3867 'IObjekt::dajX': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member` Whats wrong?

Comment: How is dajX declared?  You used it as data.  That error might mean it is a member function.